# Run javascript function when a button is enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want a (preferably pure javascript but jquery is acceptable too) way to run a function when the `disabled="disabled"` property is removed from a button.

Comment: can you show how you are disabling and enabling the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MutationObserver API lets you monitor elements for changes on the element.

```
var btnElement = document.getElementById("buttonId");

var observer = new MutationObserver(observerChanges);
observer.observe(btnElement, {
    attributes: true,
    subtree: opt.watchChildren,
    childList: opt.watchChildren,
    characterData: true
});

/// when you're done observing
observer.disconnect();

function observerChanges(mutationRecord, mutationObserver) {
    console.log(mutationRecord);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get notified of DOM changes by implementing a MutationObserver.

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  if(mutations.some(function(m) { return m.attributeName == 'disabled' && !m.target.disabled; }))
  {
    alert('Button was enabled');
  }
});

observer.observe(targetButton, { attributes: true, childList: false, characterData: false });
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w3k2pkL0/)

Comment: Adding to the answer, use **observer.disconnect** method if you wanna stop observing - https://jsfiddle.net/w3k2pkL0/1/ ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.prototype.watch()`. It's supported in Firefox only, but [here's a polyfill](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583):

HTML:

```
<button id="myButton" disabled="disabled">Click</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
myButton.watch("disabled", function() {
    console.log("myButton changed!");
});

myButton.disabled = false; // "myButton changed" will be logged
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6ofvutwh/1/

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch

Comment: Should probably mention the horrendous browser support for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch#Browser_compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us the code on how you remove disabled? But here is an example from the top of my head.

```
<button class="class" id="btn1" disabled>

function remove_disable()
{
    document.getElementById('btn1').disabled = false;
    function2();
}
```

then function2

```
function function2()
{
    //somecode
}
```

Here, when we call remove_disable we remove the disabled feature on the button then run another function.

Hope this helps in  a way

Comment: I don't really know when or how disabled is removed. An external (obscured) library manages my buttons and I want to hook to the event when that library enables the button. I would expect something along the lines of `document.getElementById('btn1').onAttributeChanged` but there is no such thing.

Comment: What libraries are you using? Maybe if you don't need all of it, you can remove the whole library, else you can show us the library and maybe from there we can manage the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over when this change is done, a simple callback function would be the easiest solution.

Otherwise, you can use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for when disabled property on inputs are changed.